# Calling WS-Trust secured service from WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, ws-security, rampart, ws-trust, wso2-esb

I'm looking for help on how to call WS-Trust secured SOAP service from WSO2 ESB.
The idea is to create a non-secure proxy-service which would call WS-Trust secured back-end service, so our SOAP clients wouldn't have to worry about authentication.

I've been going though the documentation and have found nothing of much value. The documentation mentions that WSO2 ESB uses Apache Rampart and more specifically Rahas module to engage WS-Trust secured services, yet there are no examples on how to configure, for example - security token service address.

So far i've found this blog post http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/11/05/how-to-invoke-secured-backend-service-using-wso2-esb/

It runs a similar scenario but without WS-Trust. It uses Rampart configuration inside WS-Policy files, but Rampart configuration doesn't support any WS-Trust attributes.

I've also found this: http://ask.programmershare.com/279_17604398/
Which is more in line with what i'm looking for, but this example is doing the STS calls programmatically and even then unsuccesfully.

Is anyone aware of any examples of a succesfull configuration to call security token service -> service call itself using WSO2 ESB?